# camel-jasypt version missing in manifest file

Tags: apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix

I am trying to upgrade a bundle from Apache-ServiceMix 4.4.2 to Apache-ServiceMix 6.0.0.

When I try to install the bundle and start it, I get the following error:

```
 2015-08-14 15:23:10,567 | ERROR | ssh for user smx | ShellUtil                        | 25 - org.apache.karaf.shell.console - 3.0.4 | Exception caught while executing command
 org.apache.karaf.shell.console.MultiException: Error executing command on bundles:
    Unable to execute command on bundle 264: Unresolved constraint in bundle esb-sciquest-sims-core [264]: Unable to resolve 264.0: missing requirement [264.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel.component.jasypt)(version>=2.8.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.MultiException.throwIf(MultiException.java:92)
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.doExecute(BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.java:58)
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:50)
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.doExecute(BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.java:41)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:33)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.OsgiCommandSupport.execute(OsgiCommandSupport.java:39)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:33)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at Proxy0842edc9_242f_450f_bd6a_d84a7747d0e9.execute(Unknown Source)[:]
    at Proxy0842edc9_242f_450f_bd6a_d84a7747d0e9.execute(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:78)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:480)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:406)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:182)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:119)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:94)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.impl.jline.ConsoleImpl.run(ConsoleImpl.java:208)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh.ShellFactoryImpl$ShellImpl$1.runConsole(ShellFactoryImpl.java:158)[233:org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh.ShellFactoryImpl$ShellImpl$1$1.run(ShellFactoryImpl.java:133)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.7.0_25]
    at org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.JaasHelper.doAs(JaasHelper.java:57)[26:org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh.ShellFactoryImpl$ShellImpl$1.run(ShellFactoryImpl.java:129)[233:org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh:3.0.4]
 Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to execute command on bundle 264: Unresolved constraint in bundle esb-sciquest-sims-core [264]: Unable to resolve 264.0: missing requirement [264.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel.component.jasypt)(version>=2.8.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.doExecute(BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.java:55)
    ... 20 more
 Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle esb-sciquest-sims-core [264]: Unable to resolve 264.0: missing requirement [264.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel.component.jasypt)(version>=2.8.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3974)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2037)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:942)
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.Start.executeOnBundle(Start.java:27)
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.doExecute(BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.java:53)
    ... 20 more
 2015-08-14 15:42:58,224 | ERROR | ssh for user smx | ShellUtil                        | 25 - org.apache.karaf.shell.console - 3.0.4 | Exception caught while executing command
 org.apache.karaf.shell.console.MultiException: Error executing command on bundles:
    Unable to execute command on bundle 264: Unresolved constraint in bundle esb-sciquest-sims-core [264]: Unable to resolve 264.0: missing requirement [264.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel.component.jasypt)(version>=2.8.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.MultiException.throwIf(MultiException.java:92)
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.doExecute(BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.java:58)
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:50)
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.doExecute(BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.java:41)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:33)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.OsgiCommandSupport.execute(OsgiCommandSupport.java:39)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:33)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at Proxy0842edc9_242f_450f_bd6a_d84a7747d0e9.execute(Unknown Source)[:]
    at Proxy0842edc9_242f_450f_bd6a_d84a7747d0e9.execute(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:78)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:480)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:406)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:182)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:119)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:94)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.impl.jline.ConsoleImpl.run(ConsoleImpl.java:208)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh.ShellFactoryImpl$ShellImpl$1.runConsole(ShellFactoryImpl.java:158)[233:org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh.ShellFactoryImpl$ShellImpl$1$1.run(ShellFactoryImpl.java:133)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.7.0_25]
    at org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.JaasHelper.doAs(JaasHelper.java:57)[26:org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh.ShellFactoryImpl$ShellImpl$1.run(ShellFactoryImpl.java:129)[233:org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh:3.0.4]
 Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to execute command on bundle 264: Unresolved constraint in bundle esb-sciquest-sims-core [264]: Unable to resolve 264.0: missing requirement [264.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel.component.jasypt)(version>=2.8.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.doExecute(BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.java:55)
    ... 20 more
 Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle esb-sciquest-sims-core [264]: Unable to resolve 264.0: missing requirement [264.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel.component.jasypt)(version>=2.8.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3974)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2037)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:942)
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.Start.executeOnBundle(Start.java:27)
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.doExecute(BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.java:53)
    ... 20 more
 2015-08-14 15:43:47,306 | ERROR | ssh for user smx | ShellUtil                        | 25 - org.apache.karaf.shell.console - 3.0.4 | Exception caught while executing command
 org.apache.karaf.shell.console.MultiException: Error executing command on bundles:
    Unable to execute command on bundle 265: Unresolved constraint in bundle esb-sciquest-sims-core [265]: Unable to resolve 265.0: missing requirement [265.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel.component.jasypt)(version>=2.8.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.MultiException.throwIf(MultiException.java:92)
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.doExecute(BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.java:58)
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:50)
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.doExecute(BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.java:41)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:33)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.OsgiCommandSupport.execute(OsgiCommandSupport.java:39)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:33)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at Proxy0842edc9_242f_450f_bd6a_d84a7747d0e9.execute(Unknown Source)[:]
    at Proxy0842edc9_242f_450f_bd6a_d84a7747d0e9.execute(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:78)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:480)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:406)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:182)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:119)[25:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:94)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.impl.jline.ConsoleImpl.run(ConsoleImpl.java:208)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh.ShellFactoryImpl$ShellImpl$1.runConsole(ShellFactoryImpl.java:158)[233:org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh.ShellFactoryImpl$ShellImpl$1$1.run(ShellFactoryImpl.java:133)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.7.0_25]
    at org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.JaasHelper.doAs(JaasHelper.java:57)[26:org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh.ShellFactoryImpl$ShellImpl$1.run(ShellFactoryImpl.java:129)[233:org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh:3.0.4]
 Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to execute command on bundle 265: Unresolved constraint in bundle esb-sciquest-sims-core [265]: Unable to resolve 265.0: missing requirement [265.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel.component.jasypt)(version>=2.8.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.doExecute(BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.java:55)
    ... 20 more
 Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle esb-sciquest-sims-core [265]: Unable to resolve 265.0: missing requirement [265.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel.component.jasypt)(version>=2.8.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3974)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2037)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:942)
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.Start.executeOnBundle(Start.java:27)
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.doExecute(BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.java:53)
    ... 20 more
```

After looking at responses to similar questions, I was able to narrow this problem down to the manifest files for this bundle.

Here is the manifest file compiled for Apache-ServiceMix 4.4.2:

```
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
 Export-Package: edu.usc.its.eis.es.esb.sciquest.core;uses:="org.apache
  .camel,org.apache.commons.lang,org.apache.camel.builder,org.apache.ca
  mel.model,org.apache.camel.builder.xml,org.apache.camel.util.jsse,org
  .apache.camel.component.http4"
 Built-By: sajmera
 Tool: Bnd-1.15.0
 Bundle-Name: USC Enterprise Service Bus :: esb-sciquest-core
 Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
 Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_65
 Bundle-Version: 2.0.1.SNAPSHOT
 Bnd-LastModified: 1438904309060
 Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
 Bundle-Description: message routing mediation engine to handle various
   workflows between systems
 Import-Package: org.apache.camel;version="[2.8,3)",org.apache.camel.bu
  ilder;version="[2.8,3)",org.apache.camel.builder.xml;version="[2.8,3)
  ",org.apache.camel.component.http4;version="[2.8,3)",**org.apache.camel
  .component.jasypt;version="[2.8,3)"**,org.apache.camel.model;version="[
  2.8,3)",org.apache.camel.osgi;version="[2.8,3)",org.apache.camel.util
  .jsse;version="[2.8,3)",org.apache.commons.lang;version="[2.6,3)",org
  .osgi.service.blueprint;version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)"
 Bundle-SymbolicName: esb-sciquest-core
```

And here is the manifest file compiled for Apache-ServiceMix 6.0.0

```
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
 Export-Package: edu.usc.its.eis.es.esb.sciquest.core;uses:="org.apache
  .camel,org.apache.commons.lang,org.apache.camel.builder,org.apache.ca
  mel.model,org.apache.camel.builder.xml,org.apache.camel.util.jsse,org
  .apache.camel.component.http4"
 Built-By: sajmera
 Tool: Bnd-1.15.0
 Bundle-Name: USC Enterprise Service Bus :: esb-sciquest-core
 Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
 Bundle-Version: 2.0.1.SNAPSHOT
 Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_25
 Bnd-LastModified: 1439592171635
 Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
 Bundle-Description: message routing mediation engine to handle various
   workflows between systems
 Import-Package: org.apache.camel;version="[2.15,3)",org.apache.camel.b
  uilder;version="[2.15,3)",org.apache.camel.builder.xml;version="[2.15
  ,3)",org.apache.camel.component.http4;version="[2.15,3)",**org.apache.c
  amel.component.jasypt**,org.apache.camel.model;version="[2.15,3)",org.a
  pache.camel.osgi;version="[2.15,3)",org.apache.camel.util.jsse;versio
  n="[2.15,3)",org.apache.commons.lang;version="[2.6,3)",org.osgi.servi
  ce.blueprint;version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)"
 Bundle-SymbolicName: esb-sciquest-core
```

Would you guys know why version number is missing for org.apache.camel.component.jasypt in the manifest file compiled for ServiceMix6.0?